# TRPC: JSON response from createNextApiHandler gets interrupted

Tags: next.js, prisma, render.com, trpc

Issue

- Some queries and mutations now produce `Unexpected end of JSON input` or `Unterminated string in JSON at position` errors
- This started happening after rebuilding with an unrelated update. It works locally, but not on the host.

Stack (Turborepo)

- api (Next.js v13.4.13)

  - page/api/trpc/[trpc].ts
- client (Next.js v13.4.13)

  - Connects to api using rewrites in next.config.ts
- trpc

  - routers
  - ...
- infra: render.com
- orm: prisma

Code

```
// apps/api/pages/api/trpc/[trpc].ts
export default createNextApiHandler({
  router: appRouter,
  createContext: createTRPCContext,
});

// apps/client/next.config.ts
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/trpc/:path*",
        destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/api/trpc/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
```

Reponse Sample

```
// status: 200 GET
[
    {
        "result": {
            "data": {
                "json": [
                    {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": "uuid",
                                "label": "label",
                                "status": "statusA",
                                "history": [
                                    {
                                        "creatorA // => creatorAccount
```

```
// status: 200 POST
[
    {
        "result": {
            "data": {
                "json": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "meta": {
                    "v
```

What I've tried

- Directly connecting to the api with ThunderClient, etc.

  - No change => It seems not to be a client-side configuration mistake
- Setting response headers

  - Fixing Content-Type and Content-Encoding didn't make any difference
- Fixing versions of npm modules

  - No change

Ensuring all queries/mutations work as before

Answer (score 0):

CORS settings were not set and I added, the issue is resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).